# get item slot from ItemStack

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am recently facing a problem that I can't get throught: how do I get the slot of an item?

let's say my code looks like that

```
        ItemStack[] items = inv.getContents();
        for (ItemStack item : items) {
            if (item != null) {
                if (position < 27 && position > -1) {
  SOMETHING HERE LIKE     --->  item.getRawSlot()
                }
            } else {
            }
        }
```

But the method getRawSlot() is not valid for item class, what can I do?

Comment: Implement `ItemStack.getRawSlot()`.

Comment: You're saying you need to know if `item` is in `items[0]`, `items[342]`, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't know the index of your current array item when using a `for-each` loop.   You'll have to use a regular `for` loop with an explicit index:

```
for (int = 0 ; i < items.length; ++i) {
    Item item = items[i]; 
    if (i < 27 && i > -1) {
        // do something here like item.getRawSlot();
    }
    // another example of something you could now do that you
    // couldn't do using for-each
    items[i] = new Item(...);
}
```